# Bellman-Ford Algorithms and Number of Steps

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, shortest-path, bellman-ford

Suppose there is a Directed Graph with `100-Vertexes` such as `V_1---> V_2 ---> ... ---> V_100`

All weights of edges is 1. we want to use `Bellman-Ford` Algorithm to find the shortest path between vertex 1 `(V_1)` to other vertexes. this algorithms in each step inspect all edges in arbitrary order. if in one step the shortest path between `V_1` to all other vertexes `not changed` (from previous values), the algorithm will be stops !. `the number of steps in this algorithms` `depends on the order of inspecting edges`.

> what is the Max and Min number of steps in this algorihms?

```
a) 100, 10000

b) 2, 100

c) 100, 100

d) 2, 99
```

anyone could describe me why option (2) is selected for the answer of this question ?

Comment: Seems like school is getting to you... :-) I think you have to solve this one yourself, how else will you learn anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "such as V_1---> V_2 ---> ... ---> V_100"? That's a linked list. Is it a linked list or a general graph?

Comment: No, it's a Directed graph v_1 has an edge to v_2 and has an edge to v_3 and so on. @IVlad

Comment: @IVlad a linked list is a special case of a graph, right?

Comment: @Beginner - right. I was just confused about whether or not the OP's graph is always a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

The Bellman-Ford algorithm is given at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm).

It is two steps if `V_1` and `V_2` are chosen. It won't get any better assuming `V_1` to `V_1` is not an allowed input, which could be done with a single step.

The worst case is if `V_1` and `V_100` are given as input: this takes 100 steps to arrive at V_100.

---

The question is: given the possible inputs, what is the best and what is the worst case that can happen for the distance between to edges in your example graph?

**Example**: the input is `Bellman-Ford(Vertices, Edges, Soucre)`
What will happen? 
In this particular example the Vertices are V_1 to V_100, Edges are E_1 (from V_1 to V_2, etc.) and the Source is V_1.

Step 1: start at beginning, i.e. we know the shortest path from `V_1` to `V_1`. 
Step 2: follow one of the edges. There is only one edge, lets call it E_1. This edge is from `V_1` to `V_2`. The algorithm will follow this edge. Now we now the shortest path from `V_1` to `V_2` takes 1 step along this edge. The number of steps for V_1 and V_2 is 2. This is the shortest non-trivial path.

Now determine what will be the result for the distance between V_1 and V_100. There are 99 edges between `V_1` and `V_100`, since `E_99` goes from `V_99` to `V_100`. How many steps will this take? Can there be a longer path for this specific graph?

Comment: would you please add a bit detail? i didnt get it !

Comment: how we can do it BL(v_1 , v_2)? i think always we should calculate shortest path from v_1 to all otherss?